# How to get a sub-array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, sub-array

So I have an array, and I'm trying to get a sub-array from it.

[image: Array]

```
x = np.arange(0,100).reshape((10, 10))
```

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

So, to get the first two rows and two columns, I use the following. But when I try to get rows {5,6,7} and columns {3,4,5}, it is not giving me what I want.

```
x[:2,:2]
x[5:7,3:5]
```

This is what I need, out of the initial array.
[image: What I need]
But I do not understand how to get it.

Comment: Can you post your array in text format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slices are half-open intervals. You need to increase each upper bound by one.

```
>>> x[5:8,3:6]
array([[53, 54, 55],
       [63, 64, 65],
       [73, 74, 75]])
```

Also, the indices start at 0, which is why `x[:2,:2]` worked the way you expected, despite your expectation being off. `:2` is short for `0:2`, not `1:2`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the subset of the array you indicated, you would use x[5:8,3:6].

Remember that in Python, slice indices do not include the last element.  [0, 1, 2, 3][:1] gives you just [0], for example.

Answer (score 2):

simply slice the array

`x[5:8,3:6]`